# How can I get the "boxRain" effect to work in nivo-slider.js v.3.0?

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, nivo-slider

Nivo Slider v.3.01 is now responsive by default, which seems to have disabled many of the effects such as "boxRain". Does anyone know how to get the "boxRain" effects going again?

I found this solution to get some of the effects working again such as "sliceUp" etc. but can't find a solution for "boxRain" or the other "box" effects:

Solution for fixing "slice" effects in Nivo Slider v.3.01:

`.nivoSlider img {
    vertical-align: baseline !important;
    max-width: none !important;
}`

Comment: Strange, this page says it still includes box rain as an effect: http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/

Comment: The jquery_nivo.js on that page is a different size than the new 3.01 file: http://support.dev7studios.com/discussions/nivo-slider/1727-using-the-new-v301-some-transistions-not-working  

It looks like the Nivo Slider folks are aware of the issue and are currently working on a fix. It seems to be mostly effecting people trying to use "box" effects (the best ones)...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Only the slice effects for left/right and the fading effects are working. All box effects, sliceUp , etc aren´t working.

I´m using nivo-slider 3.2 with jquery 1.9.

Comment: This should be a comment, not a answer.